# pandas: create a row per combination of index value and external list value

Tags: python, pandas, python-itertools

I am trying to create a row in a dataframe that would represent a unique combination between the index of the `df` and a value in a list.

A short example would be more explicit than lots of words!

```
           Id
0    16342939
1    16346727
```

and the list

```
Location = ['DC1', 'DC2', 'store1','store2']
```

what I am looking to achieve is this:

```
           Id    Loc
0    16342939    DC1
0    16342939    DC2
0    16342939 store1
0    16342939 store2
1    16346727    DC1
1    16346727    DC2
1    16346727 store1
1    16346727 store2
```

I am asking what tool should I use to do that in python. I have thought and searched about `itertools` and `combinations`. But it does not seem to do the trick. I have also thought of merging the list, but it does not work either.

A recommendation on the tool to use would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with list comprehension and the pandas explode function.

First populate the "Loc" column with the Location list. To do this you need to use list comprehension otherwise pandas will try to populate the rows of the column with the individual list entries instead of the entire list. Sample code for the list comprehension is below:

`df['Loc'] = [Location for i in range(len(df))]`

Then you can use the explode function to split the pandas explode function to split the list data into seperate rows with the same "Id" value. Sample code for this is below:

`df = df.explode('Loc')`

The final result will be the following:

```
         Id     Loc
0  16342939     DC1
0  16342939     DC2
0  16342939  store1
0  16342939  store2
1  16346727     DC1
1  16346727     DC2
1  16346727  store1
1  16346727  store2
```

Comment: You can do `df['Loc'] = Location * len(df)` I think

Comment: crazy this explode function! it did the trick. thanks!

Comment: Erfan, I'll try that out too

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the [expand_grid](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.expand_grid.html) from the `pyjanitor` library

```
others = {"Id": df.Id.array, 'Loc': Location}

In [87]: janitor.expand_grid(others = others)
Out[87]: 
         Id     Loc
0  16342939     DC1
1  16342939     DC2
2  16342939  store1
3  16342939  store2
4  16346727     DC1
5  16346727     DC2
6  16346727  store1
7  16346727  store2
```

You could get more speed with numpy:

```
left = np.repeat(df.Id.array, len(Location))
right = np.resize(Location, len(df)*len(Location))
combo =zip(['Id', 'Loc'],  map(pd.Series, (left, right)))
pd.concat(dict(combo), axis = 'columns')
         Id     Loc
0  16342939     DC1
1  16342939     DC2
2  16342939  store1
3  16342939  store2
4  16346727     DC1
5  16346727     DC2
6  16346727  store1
7  16346727  store2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
>>> df.merge(pd.Series(Location, name = 'Loc'), how = "cross")
         Id     Loc
0  16342939     DC1
1  16342939     DC2
2  16342939  store1
3  16342939  store2
4  16346727     DC1
5  16346727     DC2
6  16346727  store1
7  16346727  store2
```